# How to configure an ember-rails 1.13 app to work with the JSON API spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data, json-api

I have a Rails app that uses ActiveModelSerializers (set to serialize json using the JSON API format) and the `ember-data` gem to add Ember.js and Ember Data to the asset pipeline. All of the JavaScript is written using CoffeeScript.

We have set our application adapter to use the `DS.JSONAPIAdapter`:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend
  namespace: 'api/v1'
```

We are also setting the the serializer:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend()
```

However, we are getting errors when trying to route to the page that lists the models.

How can we configure this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turns out that the only thing that we needed to do was to specify the application adapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend
  namespace: 'api/v1'
```

The reason we were getting an error is because of the associations. Ember was failing to route because of a broken `has_many` relationship on the model.

Another thing that we needed to do was to handle underscored attribute keys. [Ember Data's `JSONAPISerializer` only knows how to map hyphenated attributes](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/974#issuecomment-120741645). We added this code to handle the mapping:

```
DS.JSONAPISerializer.reopen
  keyForAttribute: (key) ->
    Ember.String.underscore(key)

  keyForRelationship: (key) ->
    Ember.String.underscore(key)
```